# Maven how to include a Java project as a dependency

Tags: java, maven

I have the following structure

```
-->Project1 (Java SE Project)
---->src (My Java Code)

-->Project2 (Maven Project)
---->pom.xml
---->src
------->main
------->test
```

In Eclipse, I can configure the build path of the maven project to include Project1 and it runs fine in the IDE. However, I realized that it seems when I want to run it as a command

```
mvn test-compile
```

the Project2 can't find the project. I am thinking I need to somehow reference it in my pom.xml (which then, I can ignore the step in Eclipse to configure it on the build path).

The error is

```
[ERROR] package foo does not exist
```

The Project1 is not really being compiled into a .jar so that isn't the solution. I want the actual entire project as a reference somehow.

Comment: is it absolutely not an option to build jar from P1? Although it might be possible to do what you want, it would be a very dirty solution, esp for production use. Another approach would be to create a multi-module maven project and add P1 as a maven module.
PS: on a lower level, it would be possible to include the compiled classes of P1 into the classpath of P2

Comment: I will try to generate a jar instead. So for my pom.xml, would I simply add a dependency to that jar?

Comment: yes, after generating the jar and `mvn install`ing it, you should be able to reference it by its groupId & artifactId & version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead what I did was just convert the project1 to a maven project and in project2, added the dependency without needing to generate the jar. Seems like maven is smart enough to find the project and not look into the .m2 version (like if I did a mvn install).